# ¿Cómo sacar un residuo a dos número de tipo de dato float en C++?

Tags: c++, float, math, modulos

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual utiliza números muy grandes, y cuando uso el % sólo me permite utilizar tipo de variables int o long, y dichos tipos de datos no pasa de un número de 10 dígitos, por lo cual utilicé los tipos de datos float (aunque los double también me vendrían bien)

La cuestión es que, al utilizar el operador `%` sólo me aceptan tipo de datos int o long, los cuales no me sirven, he tratado de buscar cuáles soluciones serían posibles, la más cercana que tuve fue utilizar una función llamada fmod, el cual puede hacer ese clase de operaciones (se invoca con las librerías math.h y stdio.h), la cuestión es que al utilizarlas en mi programa con un fmod(a,b) con un números de más de 10 dígitos hay inconsistencias bastantes extrañas e inexactas (a fin de cuentas utilizo recursión en el programa que estoy haciendo)

Investigando me percaté de que existe un tipo de módulo que puede operar con floats, creo que era así: `%f` , pero no sé qué librería hay que usar (o siquiera que sea cierto).

Conoces algún módulo o función que pueda calcular el residuo con dos tipos de dato float?
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones, ¿al menos podrías mostrar un [mcve]? Saludos

Comment: El tipo de dato float se almacena como punto flotante binario es decir al llegar a numeros grandes contiene un valor aproximado y va ignorando las unidades.  Como indica Mauricio Contreras, deberias publicar en tu pregunta algunos casos de numeros especificos, preferiblemente con el codigo que reproduce los resultados que observas.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de los valores numéricos a los cuales les quieres calcular el resto? No importa que los mismos no sean compatibles con tipo `int` o `long`. Necesito saber la magnitud de los valores que estás dividiendo para poder darte una respuesta adecuada. Saludos

Comment: Tu problema creo que no es tanto por la recursión sino por la precisión de los números flotantes: cuanto más grandes sean los número, menor precisión tienen, hasta el punto de "saltarse" grandes cantidades. Puedes leer más sobre esto [acá](https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-spacing-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/) (en inglés).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Estoy haciendo un programa el cual utiliza números muy grandes

¿Cómo de grandes?

Los tipos nativos tienen sus restricciones. Así, el tipo `float` te ofrece 6 dígitos representativos (te puedes fiar de su valor), mientras que `double` ofrece, típicamente, 15. Estos valores los tienes a tu disposición a través de la plantilla `std::numeric_limits<>`:

```
std::cout << "Precision de float: " << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 << '\n'
          << "Precision de double: " << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << '\n';
```

Esto quiere decir que, si por ejemplo usas números en el rango 1e<sup>6</sup> no podrías recuperar ningún decimal al usar `float` y solo podrías recuperar 6 decimales si usases `double`.

En cambio, si usas números en el rango 1e<sup>15</sup> o superiores... olvídate de los decimales porque lo que obtendrás es únicamente basura.

Los números en coma flotante ofrecen la ventaja de admitir números enormes a costa de sacrificar la precisión... y esta siempre es relativa al número que pretendas almacenar.

Y dicho esto, para calcular la parte decimal de un número basta con calcular su parte entera y hacer la resta:

```
float numero = 12.34;
std::cout << numero << '\n';

float parte_entera = std::floor(numero);
float parte_decimal = numero - parte_entera;

std::cout << parte_entera << ' ' << parte_decimal << '\n';
```

Si ya quieres esa parte decimal en forma de número entero... te toca multiplicar por el factor que te interese:

```
int parte_decimal_int = static_cast<int>(parte_decimal * 100);
std::cout << parte_decimal_int << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi propuesta es muy diferente al uso de tipos numéricos propuesto por la otra respuesta y propuesto por el mismo OP.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular el valor del resto (residuo) de la división entera (euclidea) de números muy grandes (10 o más dígitos), aunque el OP no da pistas de si ambos números (dividendo y divisor) son de estas magnitudes.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Mi solución parte en principio de usar valores para divisor de 8 dígitos o menos, no sabiendo si hay necesidad de usar divisores más grandes. Y valores de dividendo tan grandes como se desee.

Los valores enteros no se tratarán de forma numérica, sino como cadena, y serán convertidos a números en tamaños seguros (menores a 2^31).

Siendo los sistemas de cómputo actuales suficientemente capaces de representar valores del orden de 32 bits (`(2^31) - 1`). Lo que haremos es desarrollar el algoritmo de la [división euclídea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_eucl%C3%ADdea) para hallar el resto de dividir `M / D` (enteros) con `M` teniendo `n` dígitos y `D` teniendo hasta 8 dígitos y siendo `D` diferente de cero (0).

**Algoritmo de la división**

Recordemos el algoritmo de la división tal como nos lo fue enseñado en la escuela (probablemente no a todos les enseñaron el mismo algoritmo, pero la idea se entiende fácilmente). Tomamos el dividendo y lo escribimos seguido de una linea vertical lo suficientemente larga, y luego escribimos el divisor al mismo nivel del dividendo del lado derecho de la linea y lo subrayamos con una linea horizontal. Algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```sh
124456 | 123
       |------
       |
       |
       |
```

Sabemos que para dividir estas cifras tomaremos los primeros 3 dígitos del dividendo ya que el divisor cabe justo 1 vez en 124, por lo tanto el resto de dividir 124 entre 123 es 1. Luego *"bajamos"* las siguientes 2 cifras (45) y realizamos la división usando el resto anterior junto a 4 y 5, para formar la cifra 145:

```sh
 124456 | 123
-123    |------
 ---    | 10
   145  |
        |
```

Continuamos de esta manera hasta que todos los valores del dividendo han *"bajado"*:

```sh
 124456 | 123
-123    |------
 ---    | 101
   145  |
  -123  |
   ---  |
    226 |


 124456 | 123
-123    |------
 ---    | 1011
   145  |
  -123  |
   ---  |
    226 |
   -123 |
    --- |
    103 |
```

El resto es entonces 103.

Usando este algoritmo podemos hacer divisiones de números de 9 cifras entre números de hasta 8 cifras como divisor máximo.

Al final siempre obtendremos el resto de la división.

En el caso de nuestro programa, lo importante es siempre obtener un valor de dividendo de 9 cifras a partir del resto de cada división.

Podríamos entonces implementar un programa que, dada una representación de cadena de un número de muchos dígitos (más de 9) podemos calcular el valor del resto de dividirlo por otro número de 8 cifras o menos.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente programa calcula el resto de cualquier cifra numérica (sin importar su tamaño) al dividirlo entre un número de hasta 8 dígitos:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string dividendo;
  string divisor;
  cout << "Introduzca el dividendo: ";
  cin >> dividendo;
  cout << "Introduzca el divisor: ";
  cin >> divisor;
  
  if(dividendo.size() < divisor.size()) // <- caso divisor más grande que dividendo
  {
    cout << "Resto: " << dividendo << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  if(divisor.size() > 8) // caso divisor con 9 o más dígitos
  {
    cout << "Divisor fuera de rango!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  
  int end = dividendo.size(); // tamaño del dividendo
  int pos = 9; // <- cantidad máxima de dígitos en cada división
  int resto;

  if(end < pos)  // <-caso en que dividendo tiene menos de 9 dígitos
  {
    resto = stoi(dividendo) % stoi(divisor);
    cout << "Resto: " << resto << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  int numOfDigits = pos - divisor.size();
  string part = dividendo.substr(0, pos);
  bool last = false;
  
  // primer cálculo
  resto = stoi(part) % stoi(divisor);
  
  while(!last)
  {
    if(pos + numOfDigits < end)
    {
      part = to_string(resto);
      numOfDigits = 9 - part.size();
      part += dividendo.substr(pos, numOfDigits);
      pos += numOfDigits;
    }
    else
    {
      part = to_string(resto);
      part += dividendo.substr(pos);
      last = true;
    }
    resto = stoi(part) % stoi(divisor);
  }
  cout << "Remainder: " << resto << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Podemos extender esta solución al caso genérico para cualquier tamaño de dividendo y divisor, pero eso requerirá una lógica un poco más avanzada, mas no imposible.

Una corrida del programa para las siguientes cifras produce el siguiente resultado:

```sh
Introduzca el dividendo: 834239010178634589623587264591
Introduzca el divisor: 12345678
Resto: 2842411
```

Lo puedes comprobar en cualquier calculadora en línea como [esta](https://www.dcode.fr/modulo-n-calculator).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema planteado.